# Discord music bot using VoiceClient not recognizing that song is already playing

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def play(self, ctx, *, url=''):
    async with ctx.typing():
        if url == '':
            if ctx.message.guild.voice_client.is_playing():
                ctx.message.guild.voice_client.pause()
                user = ctx.message.author.mention
                await ctx.send(f"Bot was paused by {user}")
            if ctx.message.guild.voice_client.is_paused():
                ctx.message.guild.voice_client.resume()
                user = ctx.message.author.mention
                await ctx.send(f"Bot was resume by {user}")
            else:
                await ctx.send('Nothing to play')

        else:
            if servers.get(ctx.message.guild.id) == None:
                servers[ctx.message.guild.id] = {}

                # try:

                servers[ctx.message.guild.id][len(
                    servers[ctx.message.guild.id])] = (url)
                await ctx.send(
                    f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url +
                    '``\n<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Added to queue:** ``{}'
                    .format(url) + "``")

                await self.startPlaying(ctx, 0,
                                        servers[ctx.message.guild.id])
```

I'm trying to implement this function where the URL argument can be optional, if it is provided, the `else` statement executes and the bot plays the song, whereas if the argument isn't provided, the bot should either pause or resume depending on the validation.

I think my code is correct, but for some reason it doesn't work as intended.

Discord Screenshot:

[image]

When I insert the command `-p let me -zayn` it plays the song, but when I insert just `-p` it doesn't go into the `if` blocks, and skips to the `else`. Ideally it should pause the song or resume depending on the bot's activity.

**Intended way of working:**

> `-p`

> Nothing to play (because no song is there to play in the queue)

> `-p songname`

> Added to queue: let me - zayn (PLAYS THE SONG)

> `-p`

> Pauses the song since it was already playing.

> `-p`

> Resumes the song since it was paused.

**Actual way of working:**

> `-p songname`

> Added to queue: let me - zayn (PLAYS THE SONG)

> `-p`

> Nothing to play

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which `if` statement in particular do you think is not working as indented?

Comment: The if block from line 4. In the picture that I uploaded the bot was playing the song until I inserted `-p` which then should execute the if block in line 4 in my code. instead it just skips to the else statement (line 12) in the same block.

Comment: edited the question to make it more clear ig, please look into it.

Comment: What's the result of `ctx.message.guild.voice_client.is_playing()` and `ctx.message.guild.voice_client.is_paused()` at the beginning of the `if url == ''` block?

Comment: its false before actually playing the song, and changes to True, False once song starts playing.

Comment: After you `await self.startPlaying`, what's the state of `is_playing` and `is_paused`? Also try printing out the state of those two variables when you run that command - it may give us an idea of what's happening to the bot. If I'm interpreting this correctly, the `-p` command should pause/unpause the music if something is playing right now, and send that if it isn't?